# How to hide values of request payload in browser.?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am working on MERN tech. I just noticed when I try to login user his credentials are shown in the request payload as it is. What to do with request payload.

Comment: Why do you think you need to hide the credentials of a user that entered those credentials? Is this a shared machine? Are you storing the credentials in localStorage or sessionStorage?

Comment: There's no way for you to do that at least none that I have heard of. Here is a helpful post on the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630002/angular-5-is-there-way-hide-api-call-or-make-it-private